# What is Mixin Based Inheritance in Dart?

Tags: inheritance, dart, dart-pub

This is definition of Mixin Based Programming from the official Docs,

> Mixin-based inheritance means that although every class (except for
>   Object) has exactly one superclass, a class body can be reused in
>   multiple class hierarchies.

Can anyone explain this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mixins are a limited way to reduce the limitations of single-inheritance (in contrary to for example [C++ which allows multiple inheritance](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/multiple-inheritance-in-c/))

Mixins allow to inherit implementations of methods from **one** superclass **and** one or more mixin classes.

See also

- [When to use mixins and when to use interfaces in Dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45901297/when-to-use-mixins-and-when-to-use-interfaces-in-dart)

Answer (score 6):

[image]
[image]

From https://medium.com/flutter-community/dart-what-are-mixins-3a72344011f3

⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀