# How to call Super Class method if there is a Mixin with a method with the same name

Tags: flutter, dart

### Duplicate method behavior

The [code, here as a Gist,](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/10e4a4fe0cc01c7eb5ec926ff9a4cebb) will print `e`. If I remove the override, i.e. remove `output` from `Baz`, it will print `w` from `Bar`.
This leads me to the conclusion that the method "priority" is `own class` `->` `mixin` `->` `super class`.

If I add more mixins, e.g. like this:

```dart
mixin Zoo {
  output() {
    print('j');
  }
}

class Baz extends Foo with Bar, Zoo {
// ...
```

Now, the output is `j`. If I swap around `Bar` and `Zoo`:

```dart
class Baz extends Foo with Zoo, Bar {
// ...
```

Now, the outpt is `w` again.
Consequently, I would define the priority like this: `own class` `->` `last mixin` `->` `nth-last mixin` `->` `super class`.

### Question

Is there any way for me to *control* this behavior, i.e. call the super call method even when a `mixin` has a method with the same name?

#### Why

You might be askin why I would want to do this and not just rename the methods.
Well, in Flutter all `State`'s have a `dispose` method and if I have a `mixin` that has `dispose` method as well, it will break the `State`'s functionality because the `mixin`'s `dispose` method takes priority as illustrated above.

### Additional notes

`super.output` will call the mixin method as well, which is why that does not work. You can try adding the following constructor to `Baz`:

```dart
Baz() {
  super.output();
}
```

Even if this worked, it would not help as the `dispose` method in the Flutter case is called from the outside.

Comment: That is simply not possible. In any case, it's usually not a good thing to extensively use mixins in widgets. They are not very scalable

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In mixins - **the order in which the mixins are declared is very important**.

When you apply a mixin to a class,

Mixins in Dart work by creating a new class that layers the implementation of the mixin on top of a superclass to create a new class — it is not “on the side” but “on top” of the superclass, so there is no ambiguity in how to resolve lookups 
[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45901297/when-to-use-mixins-and-when-to-use-interfaces-in-dart/45903671#45903671)

```
class A {
  String getMessage() => 'A';
}

class B {
  String getMessage() => 'B';
}

class P {
  String getMessage() => 'P';
}

class AB extends P with A, B {}

class BA extends P with B, A {}

void main() {
  String result = '';

  AB ab = AB();
  result += ab.getMessage();

  BA ba = BA();
  result += ba.getMessage();

  print(result);
}
```

Both, AB and BA classes extend the P class with A and B mixins but in a different order. All three A, B and P classes have a method called getMessage.

First, we call the getMessage method of the AB class, then the getMessage method of the BA class.

And the output will be `BA`.

[Want to learn more ? Details Explanation ~>](https://medium.com/flutter-community/dart-what-are-mixins-3a72344011f3)