# In Dart, how can I call a superclass method shadowed by a mixin method?

Tags: dart

I have a class `A` and it extends `B` and mixes in `C` like the code below. How do I make it work?

```
class A extends B with C {
  @override
  int getValue() {
    // Call's C's getValue.
    super.getValue();
    // Now I want to call B's getValue. How do I do that?
    return B.getValue(); // Doesn't work.
  }
}

class B {
  int getValue() {
    return 1;
  }
}

class C {
  int getValue() {
    return 2;
  }
}
```

How can I execute B's `getValue`? Thanks.

Comment: does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57035710/how-to-call-super-class-method-if-there-is-a-mixin-with-a-method-with-the-same-n) help you?

Comment: The linked answer only tells you how to reorder mixins to make one of them callable using super. It does not provide a way to call multliple of them, or to call the member from the superclass, so I don't think it answers this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mixin method from `C` shadows the method from `B`, so you can't use `super` directly to refer to the `B` method. You need to introduce a way to access it.

What you can do is to put a private redirecting function in between the `B` class and the `C` mixin application:

```dart
class A extends B with _Helper, C {
  int getValue() {
    // It's C
    super.getValue();
    // Now I want to get B's getValue how do it?
    return super._getValueFromB();
  }
}
    
class B {
  int getValue() {
    return 1;
  }
}
mixin C {
  int getValue() {
    return 2;
  }
}
mixin _Helper on B {
  int _getValueFromB() => super.getValue();
}
```

Since the mixin application order is B, B-with-_Helper, B-with-_Helper-with-C, the `super` of the B-with-_Helper superclass is `B`, and the `_getValueFromB` will access it correctly.