# How to invoke an identical named function from the extending class instead of the mixin

Tags: flutter, dart, mixins, superclass

Consider the following code snippet:

```
void main() {
  Band myBand = new Band();
  myBand.guitar();
  print("Number of players " + myBand.players.toString());
}

class Rock {
  int players=2;
  void guitar() {
    print('Rock guitar');
  }
}

mixin Jazz {
  int players=1;
  void guitar() {
    print('Jazz guitar');
  }
}

class Band extends Rock with Jazz {

}
```

Here I have the class **Band** which extends **Rock** and the mixin **Jazz**. Both have a property and a method of the same name - `players` and `guitar`.

If I now subclass Band and invoke the `guitar` method or query the player `property` I get:

> Jazz guitar 
>   Number of players 1

Obviously for some reason the mixin is of higher importance. What do I have to do to call the properties or the methods of the extending class **Rock** and not from the mixin, from my subclass **myBand**?

Comment: Here's a got post abouut mixin and how the order works: https://medium.com/flutter-community/https-medium-com-shubhamhackzz-dart-for-flutter-mixins-in-dart-f8bb10a3d341

Answer (score 0):

> Mixins in Dart work by creating a new class that layers the
>   implementation of the mixin on top of a superclass to create a new
>   class — it is not “on the side” but “on top” of the superclass, so
>   there is no ambiguity in how to resolve lookups.

Check [When to use mixins and when to use interfaces in Dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45901297/when-to-use-mixins-and-when-to-use-interfaces-in-dart/45903671#45903671)