# What is the syntax for assigning a `class ` with `=` in Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

This is an example of MobX:

```dart
import 'package:mobx/mobx.dart';
 
// This is our generated file (we'll see this soon!)
part 'counter.g.dart';
 
// We expose this to be used throughout our project
class Counter = _Counter with _$Counter;
 
// Our store class
abstract class _Counter with Store {
  @observable
  int value = 1;
 
  @action
  void increment() {
    value++;
  }
 
  @action
  void decrement() {
    value--;
  }
}
```

I don't really understand this code: `class Counter = _Counter with _$Counter;`.

I know the usage of `with`, I just don't know why `class Counter` can be assigned with `=`, what is the meaning of the assignment operation here? Is this similar to a type alias, or is `Counter`  a subclass of `_Counter` ? I don't see this usage in Dart's guide.

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/45903671/.

Answer (score 1):

After a slight bit of research I believe the equal sign is a replacement for the `extends` keyword:

```
class A = _A with _$A;
```

is the same as:

```
class A extends _A with _$A {}
```