# Does Dart support multiple inheritance?

Tags: dart

What are the mechanisms for multiple inheritance supported by Dart?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, Dart does not support multiple implementation inheritance.

Dart has interfaces, and like most other similar languages it has multiple interface inheritance.

For implementation, there is only a single super-class chain that a class can inherit member implementations from.

Dart does have *mixins*, which allows implementation to be used by multiple classes, but not through *inheritance* as much as by *mixin application*.

Example:

```dart
class A {
  String get foo;
}
class A1 implements A {
  String get foo => "A1";
}
class A2 implements A {
  String get foo => "A2";
}
mixin B on A {
  String get foo => "B:${super.foo}";
}
class C extends A1 with B {
  String get foo => "C:${super.foo}";
}
class D extends A2 with B {
  String get foo => "D:${super.foo}";
}
void main() {
  print(C().foo); // C:B:A1
  print(D().foo); // D:B:A2
}
```

Here the same member, `B.foo`, is mixed into two different classes, with two different super-classes.

Each of the classes `C` and `D` has only a single superclass chain. The superclass of `C` is the anonymous mixin application class `A1 with B`, the superclass of `D` is the distinct mixin application class `A2 with B`. Both of these classes contain the mixin member `B.foo`.

Mixins are not multiple inheritance, but it's the closest you'll get in Dart.

Comment: Also see [lrn's older post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45903671/) explaining how mixins work.

Comment: Mixins are documented here: https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#adding-features-to-a-class-mixins

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it's quite easy. The only thing that needs to be understood is that Interfaces are not defined explicitly. Instead, Dart automatically creates Interfaces for all classes. That means you can implement a class like you would implement an interface. For pure Interfaces, there's abstract classes.

Here is how that works:

```dart
abstract class TestInterfaceA{
  String getStringA();
}

abstract class TestInterfaceB{
  String getStringB();
}

class TestInterfaceImplementer implements TestInterfaceA, TestInterfaceB{
  @override
  String getStringA() {
    return "A";
  }

  @override
  String getStringB() {
    return "B";
  }
}

main(){
  test("TestInterfaceImplementer should be able to call method from TestInterface A", () {
    TestInterfaceA testInterfaceA = TestInterfaceImplementer();

    expect(testInterfaceA.getStringA(), "A");
  });
  test("TestInterfaceImplementer should be able to call method from TestInterface B", () {
    TestInterfaceB testInterfaceB = TestInterfaceImplementer();

    expect(testInterfaceB.getStringB(), "B");
  });
}
```