# Why it prints GB's init method?

Tags: flutter, dart

The code likes below:

```
abstract class BB {
  BB() {
    print('BB Constructor');
    init();
  }
  init() {
    print('BB init');
  }
}

mixin GB on BB {
  @override
  init() {
    super.init();
    print('GB init');
  }
}

mixin PB on BB {
  @override
  init() {
    super.init();
    print('PB init');
  }
}

class WFB extends BB with GB,PB {}
```

It will print:

```
BB Constructor
BB init
GB init
PB init
```

I know the **PB's init** method will cover **GB's init** method. So why it invokes **GB's init** method.

Comment: I presume that you're asking why instantiating `WFB` would print that output.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/45903671/: `class WFB extends BB with GB, PB` creates an internal class hierarchy with `BB`, `GB`, and `PB`. (Your output is a little confusing because you put the `print` statements *after* calling `super.init()`, so your output is in the opposite order from when the `init()` methods are called.)

Comment: So what is the structure of this internal class?@jamesdlin

Comment: WFB derives from a $PB which derives from $GB which derives from BB, where $PB and $GB are synthesized classes generated from PB and GB respectively.  This is explained by the linked answer.