# Dart access to T class members

Tags: dart

I have defined a class as follows:

```dart
class Cart {
  late String chefName;
  late String chefImage;
  late int subTotal;
}
```

I'm using it as a class `T` in some methods:

```dart
delete<T>(T model) async {
  
}
```

The problem I'm facing is that since the `Cart` class is used as `T` in the method, I can't access its components, including `chefName`, and I have to cast it. However, since I have many classes like with `Cart` class and I want to use the `delete` method on them without writing multiple casting lines, I'm looking for a solution to solve this issue.

Without using casting or `instance of`, the only approach I found is using a reflector, which I couldn't make work. Is there a more practical solution to address this problem?

Comment: You could create an [interface](https://dart.dev/language/class-modifiers#interface) called `Deletable` which defines a `delete` method, and have each of your classes `implement` this interface.

Comment: @mmcdon20 how about mixins?

Comment: You can technically make it work with a mixin as well. But in this specific case delete should be an abstract method, and implemented in each of your models. Typically you would use a mixin in a scenario where you can implement the functionality directly in the mixin and inherit that functionality in the classes that use the mixin. See https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&opi=89978449&url=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45901297/when-to-use-mixins-and-when-to-use-interfaces-in-dart&ved=2ahUKEwjWmtrd04-BAxUinokEHfRqAEEQFnoECBsQAQ&usg=AOvVaw32hqqERnx8rfK2lf--GBPz