# Mixin on specific class explanation in dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I am confused with the following dart behavior, I would like to have my `mixin` on specific class, so I wrote something like that:

```
class Musician {
  callMixinPerform() {
    perform();  
  }
}

mixin MusicalPerformer on Musician {
  perform() {
    print('perform mixin');
  }
}
```

Musician class doesnt recognize `perform()` I am wondering why?
I didnt find a proper explanation in the [mixin doc](https://dart.dev/language/mixins) (or maybe I didnt understand it)
I can do something like that: (I can also create the mixin without `on`)

```
class Musician extends Child with MusicalPerformer{
  callMixinPerform() {
    perform();  
  }
}

class Child {}
mixin MusicalPerformer on Child {
  perform() {
    print('perform mixin');
  }
}
```

BUT that not exactly what I wanted, I just wanted to have a mixin on specific class.
And I would also like to know why I cant.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your notion of inheritance is backward.  To *use* a mixin named `Foo`, the class using it must use `with Foo`:

```dart
mixin Foo {
  void f() => print('From Foo');
}

class Bar with Foo { 
  void g() => f();
}
```

For the declaration `mixin MusicalPerformer on Musician`, the `on Musician` part is a *constraint* that allows only classes that derive from `Musician` to use `with MusicalPerformer`.  Note the example from the [mixin documentation](https://dart.dev/language/mixins):

> ```dart
> class SingerDancer extends Musician with MusicalPerformer {
>   // ...
> }
> ```

The constraint means that `MusicalPerformer` effectively inherits from `Musician`, not the other way around.

Also see [lrn's explanation for how Dart mixins work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45903671/), which describes the synthesized inheritance tree.

Comment: I see, I think the docs were updated as I pretty sure I didnt see that example

Comment: @Mike.R No, you just missed it.  All of the Dart documentation has links to the source, and [it hasn't been updated since June 9, 2023](https://github.com/dart-lang/site-www/blob/main/src/language/mixins.md).